# Compare the colnames within two lists of data.frames?

Tags: r, list, names

I am using a function that drops various columns from each data.frame in a list when those variables do not meet certain criteria, and I would like a convenient way to see which columns have been dropped. The real-world data.frames will have 1000s of varied `colnames`, with some overlap in those names.

It this simplified example, I would like to get a list that shows the variables of each data.frame that exist in `list1` but which are absent in `list2`.

**Input lists**

```
> list1
$A
  a b
1 2 3
$B
  c d e
1 9 8 1
$C
  f g
1 6 7

> list2
$A
  a
1 2
$B
  c d
1 9 8
$C
  g
1 7
```

**Desired output**

I'd like to keep the list structure, so that I see which columns were dropped from each data.frame.

```
$A
  b
1 3
$B
  e
1 1
$C
  f
1 6
```

**My attempts**

I've looked on SO, but have only found solutions that pertain to comparing data.frames. Keep in mind the names of the list elements (here A, B and C) will always be the same in the lists. My idea has been to use `setdiff` , or `setdiff` with `mapply`, but my tinkering has not been fruitful. What can be done?

```
## sample data
list1 <- list(A=data.frame(a=2, b=3), B=data.frame(c=9,d=8,e=1), C=data.frame(f= 6,g=7))
list2 <- list(A=data.frame(a=2), B=data.frame(c=9,d=8), C=data.frame(g=7))
desired_output <- list(A=data.frame(b=3), B=data.frame(e=1), C=data.frame(f= 6))

## attempts

# gives List 1
setdiff(list1, list2)

# gives 'Error: not compatible: Cols in x but not y: `b`.'
mapply(setdiff, x = list1, y = list2)

# gives 'Error in list1[[i]] : recursive indexing failed at level 3'
mapply(setdiff, x = colnames(list1[[i]]), y = colnames(list2[[i]]))

# gives 'list()'
mapply(setdiff, x = colnames(list1[i]), y = colnames(list2[i]))

# Gives 'Error in list1[colnams] : invalid subscript type 'list''
colnams <- list()
for(i in seq_along(list1)){
   colnams[i] <- !colnames(list1[[i]]) %in% colnames(list2[[i]]) 
}
list1[colnams]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just apply a function to subset a `data.frame` based on columns in another, and ensure it always return a `data.frame` using `drop = F`. And make sure to use `SIMPLIFY = F` in `mapply` so it always returns the list structure.

```r
mapply(function(x,y) x[,-which(names(x) %in% names(y)), drop = F], list1, list2, SIMPLIFY = F)
#> $A
#>   b
#> 1 3
#> 
#> $B
#>   e
#> 1 1
#> 
#> $C
#>   f
#> 1 6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lapply` to extract the names and `setdiff` to get those not in the other list. *No need* that the list are *sorted*.

```
x <- lapply(list1, names)
y <- lapply(list2, names)
lapply(setNames(names(x), names(x)), function(i) list1[[i]][setdiff(x[[i]], y[[i]])])
#$A
#  b
#1 3
#
#$B
#  e
#1 1
#
#$C
#  f
#1 6
```

Answer (score 1):

With `purrr`:

```
map2(.x = list1,
     .y = list2,
     ~ .x[setdiff(names(.x), names(.y))])

$A
  b
1 3

$B
  e
1 1

$C
  f
1 6
```